# Parse string into Array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, regex

I would like to parse the following string into a javascript array. Is Regex capable of performing such a task? How should I go about achieving this? I would like for the content to be capable of being dynamic other than the keys

```
<type1> <type2>
```

will remain the same. Meaning any combination of the string with any text should not matter. The keys are the delimiters.

```
Hello, I am your <type1> and <type2>!

array[0] = Hello, I am your
array[1] = <type1>
array[2] = and 
array[3] = <type2>
array[4] = !
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure whether you are looking to do this with HTML context since you have tagged the question, if so, I would not do this and look for a better way such as using a parser.

You could split on preceding whitespace and the delimiters like this.

```
var r = 'Hello, I am your <type1> and <type2>!'.split(/\s*(<[^>]*>)\s*/);
console.log(r); //=> [ 'Hello, I am your', '<type1>', 'and', '<type2>', '!' ]
```

If you want to keep the preceding whitespace and only split on the delimiters.

```
var r = 'Hello, I am your <type1> and <type2>!'.split(/(<[^>]*>)/);
console.log(r); //=> [ 'Hello, I am your ', '<type1>', ' and ', '<type2>', '!' ]
```

Comment: Will this Regex work with multiple languages given  the <type1> key remains the same?  Ie Chinese etc?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're not trying to parse HTML with JavaScript:

```
str.split(/(<[^>]+>)/)
```

It splits the strings based on things between angular brackets.

#### Result

```
["Hello, I am your ", "<type1>", " and ", "<type2>", "!"]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. String will be extremely dynamic but not html. I am  only using the tags to denote where I would like to insert a component .  i.e  Hello, I am your [button] and [image].